# What more could be required for Zend_Db to load?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

In my project directory, I have installed composer, and set up composer.json like so:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.zendframework.com/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
       "zendframework/zend-db": "2.0.*"
    }
}
```

And run:

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

which seemed to complete fine. In a file Database.php in my project directory, I have:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Automatically load class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
// and create an instance of it.
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => "host",
    'username' => "username",
    'password' => "password",
    'dbname'   => "dbname"
));
```

But when I run this script, I get:

```
$ php Database.php
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend_Db' not found in /path/project/Database.php on line 4
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /path/project/Database.php:0
```

What I am missing for the script to find the 'Zend_Db' class?

Comment: `Zend_Db` was part of ZendFw 1, your composer file requires a ZF2 module, which is a different beast all together [see the docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong way. Zend_DB is ZF1 Library. It will not work with Zf2. You need to learn Zf2 DB/Adapter first.

- http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks to use the ZendFramework 1 underscore syntax. ZF2 is all namespaced. As far as I'm aware, `Zend_Db` doesn't exist in that form in ZF2.